# toggling on/off on containing div and images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to highlight the current image highlighted by adding/removing the active class using css, javascript.

I uploaded my solution to jsfiddle, please take a look at it. Really tring to understand what is wrong with this.   http://jsfiddle.net/BEmXZ/39/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-thumbs">
    <div><a><img src=".jpg" /></a></div>
    <div><a class="active"><img src=".jpg" /></a></div> 
    <div><a><img src=".jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var make_button_active = function() {
    //Get item siblings
    var siblings =($(this).siblings());
    //Remove active class on all buttons
    siblings.each(function (index) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    );

    //Add the clicked button class
    $(this).addClass('active');
}   

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container-thumbs a").click(make_button_active);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.container-thumbs{
    width: 300px; height: 25; font-size: 18px;
}
.container-thumbs a{
    list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 4px; padding: 5px;
}
.container-thumbs div a:hover, .container-thumbs div a.active {
    background-color: #f90;
}​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`siblings` won't work, since your anchors are wrapped in divs. Try:

```
var make_button_active = function() {
    $(".container-thumbs a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container-thumbs a").click(make_button_active);
});​
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuKJ3/) (a new fiddle, since you hadn't posted yours)

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

On click, it removes active class from all the images then applies it to the current image. Also I feel you don't need `make_button_active` function at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container-thumbs a").click(function(){
         $(".container-thumbs a").removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Vbkh/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

if you change the code to this it works atleast:

```
 var make_button_active = function()
{
  //Get item siblings

  var siblings = $(".container-thumbs a");      
  siblings.each(function (index)
{
  $(this).removeClass('active');
}
);
  $(this).addClass('active');
}   

 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".container-thumbs a").click(make_button_active);
```

});

Comment: Oh didn't get the update notification about new answers, the other solutions seems to be much better.